# Android Notification data is not passed in terminated and background state

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, push-notification, android-notifications

I am working on android push notification and notification is get in all three state and then, when i tap on notification data will get in only foreground state but not get in terminated and background.

Pending intent in service file :

```
val intentVid = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    intentVid.putExtra("Id", "787789")
    intentVid.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 0,
        intentVid, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
```

Below function is called in onCreate and onNewIntent function :

```
   private fun handleNotificationEvent(intent: Intent?) {
            if (intent!!.extras != null) {
                order_status = intent.extras!!.getString("Id", "")
                if (order_status.length == 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "ID :- " + intent.extras!!.getString("Id", ""),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    )
                        .show()
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right for notification.

1. Go to the android manifest file and find launcher activity like the below
   lines example.

   ```
   <activity
     android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity"
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
2. Then use the below code in launcher activity and then pass data to your activity.

   ```
   private fun handleNotificationEvent(intent: Intent?) {
   if (intent!!.extras != null) {
       order_status = intent.extras!!.getString("Id", "")
       if (order_status.length == 6) {
           Toast.makeText(
               this,
               "ID :- " + intent.extras!!.getString("Id", ""),
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG
           )
               .show()
     }
    }
   }
   ```
3. It will help to get data from notifications in terminated and background situations.
4. In my case i will get data into splash activity.